# Prediction using Keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I learned to implement an image classifier from a code which i got from a post and it was very helpful,but i don't know how to predict on an image.I tried but its giving a Value Error.I am still a beginner

Keras Code:-

```
from __future__ import print_function
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np

#seed = 7
#np.random.seed(seed)

batch_size = 50
nb_classes = 10
nb_epoch = 150
data_augmentation = False

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 32, 32
# the CIFAR10 images are RGB
img_channels = 3

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                        input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# let's train the model using SGD + momentum (how original).

#sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
sgd= Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

if not data_augmentation:
    print('Not using data augmentation.')
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
              validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
              shuffle=True)

else:
    print('Using real-time data augmentation.')

    # this will do preprocessing and realtime data augmentation
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
        samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
        zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
        rotation_range=0,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=False)  # randomly flip images

    # compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
    # (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)
    datagen.fit(X_train)

    # fit the model on the batches generated by datagen.flow()
    model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size),
                        samples_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0],
                        nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

model.save('CIFAR10.h5')
```

My Prediction Code:-

```
from __future__ import print_function
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np
import cv2

img_rows, img_cols = 32, 32
model = load_model('CIFAR10.h5')
img = cv2.imread('D:/Study_Material/Python_3_Tutorial/PythonScripts/Machine_Learning/Project/Images/Deer.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img,(img_rows,img_cols))
Image = np.array(img)
print(model.predict(Image))
```

Error:-

```
 Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Na462\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 36
    from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Study_Material\Python_3_Tutorial\PythonScripts\Machine_Learning\Project\Keras(Prediction).py", line 12, in <module>
    print(model.predict(Image))
  File "C:\Users\Na462\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 1025, in predict
    steps=steps)
  File "C:\Users\Na462\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1817, in predict
    check_batch_axis=False)
  File "C:\Users\Na462\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 113, in _standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 32, 3)
```

Please Tell me the right way to Predict in Keras so that i can implement it on different test cases.

Comment: Is it not the right way to Predict? Because in many post i learned that convert the image in numpy array with proper dimension and pass it to the model.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because all the frameworks assume an image input is a batch of images making it a 4d tensor, instead of one image (3d tensor). To just do single image batches, expand the input to be of size (1, 32, 32, 3), the 1 in the beginning being the batch size of 1.

I do not know keras specifically very well, but since you are passing in a numpy array, you can modify your 'Image' object like so (see second to last line):

```
img_rows, img_cols = 32, 32
model = load_model('CIFAR10.h5')
img = cv2.imread('D:/Study_Material/Python_3_Tutorial/PythonScripts/Machine_Learning/Project/Images/Deer.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img,(img_rows,img_cols))
Image = np.expand_dims(np.array(img), axis=0)
print(model.predict(Image))
```